# Error in installing KnowRob (ros-hydro-knowrob)

Tags: ros, knowrob

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What I tried :

$ sudo sh -c 'echo "deb packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu precise main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'
$ sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-knowrob

Error :
E: Unable to locate package ros-hydro-knowrob

Note
sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-knowrob works fine, but I got hydro.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/137876/error-in-installing-knowrob-(ros-hydro-knowrob)/) by [ratneshmadaan](https://answers.ros.org/users/12636/ratneshmadaan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2014-03-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

KnowRob has not been released into Hydro, so it cannot be installed using apt-get. In any case, we recommend installation from source as described here http://knowrob.org/installation

---

Originally posted by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) with karma: 2673 on 2014-03-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ratneshmadaan](https://answers.ros.org/users/12636/ratneshmadaan/) on 2014-03-10**:
Got it. Thank you.

**Comment by [ratneshmadaan](https://answers.ros.org/users/12636/ratneshmadaan/) on 2014-03-10**:
I am getting this error now, after $ rosdep install knowrob

ERROR: Rosdep cannot find all required resources to answer your query
Missing resource knowrob
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/hydro/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/opt/ros/hydro/share
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/hydro/stacks

Plus, I re-installed Ubuntu 12.04 today. Gazebo is giving error as well. In mudworld, all links are not visible.

**Comment by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) on 2014-03-10**:
Then your system is not set up correctly, most probably your rosbuild/catkin setup is wrong. Please try if "roscd knowrob" works, otherwise check your setup here http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/using_rosbuild_with_catkin

**Comment by [ratneshmadaan](https://answers.ros.org/users/12636/ratneshmadaan/) on 2014-03-10**:
Maybe I am doing something foolish. Please help me out.

1.I made a ROS space:
http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment
http://docs.ros.org/independent/api/rosinstall/html/rosws_ros_tutorial.html#rosws-ros-tutorial

2.rosws merge https://raw.github.com/knowrob/knowrob/master/rosinstall/knowrob-base.rosinstall
rosws update
rosdep install knowrob
rosmake knowrob

**Comment by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) on 2014-03-10**:
There are two kinds of buildsystems, rosbuild and catkin. KnowRob still uses the older rosbuild, while the default in hydro is catkin. You can set up both systems to work together,you need to create a catkin WS first and then refer to it from rosbuild (Section 3.3 in the link I've posted).

**Comment by [ratneshmadaan](https://answers.ros.org/users/12636/ratneshmadaan/) on 2014-03-10**:
Okay, Did what you said. Now keys are unresolved. :

ratneshmadaan@ratneshmadaan-Inspiron-N5010:~/rosbuild_ws$ rosdep install knowrob
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
mod_srdl: Missing resource cmake_modules
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/hydro/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/ratneshmadaan/rosbuild_ws/rosjava_jni
ROS path [2]=/home/ratneshmadaan/rosbuild_ws/stacks/knowrob
ROS path [3]=/home/ratneshmadaan/catkin_ws/devel/rosjava_jni
ROS path [4]=/home/ratneshmadaan/catkin_ws/devel/stacks/knowrob
ROS path [5]=/home/ratneshmadaan/catkin_ws/src
ROS path [6]=/opt/ros/hydro/share
ROS path [7]=/opt/ros/hydro/stacks

**Comment by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) on 2014-03-10**:
This is in fact a ROS dependency that you can install with apt-get install ros-hydro-cmake-modules

**Comment by [ratneshmadaan](https://answers.ros.org/users/12636/ratneshmadaan/) on 2014-03-11**:
Got everything. Thanks a ton.